# Pass a unit test if it raises specific exception or returns with no exception

Tags: python, python-unittest

I would like to have a unit test that passes iff:

self.assertRaises([ImportError, NotImplmentedError, *NoExceptionWasRaised*], my_func)

In other words, the test will pass if my_func() either raises the Exception ImportError or NotImplentedError, or it completes without raising any Exception.

The test will fail if any other exception is raised.

This is what I am doing at the moment, and I think it's OK, but I think I am putting a round peg in a square hole:

```
with self.assertRaises((ImportError, NotImplementedError)):
    try:
        _x = my_func()
    except Exception:
        raise
    else:
        raise ImportError()
```

I am just changing a successful execution to raise an ImportError.

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Why is the behaviour of the function such that it either throws or doesn't throw an error for the same input? WTH are you testing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This function will try to do something using whatever modules are available.  In some cases the user will not have the module (ImportError), In some cases the user will have the module but not a dll plugin (NotImplementedError), or the user has the module and the plugin and everything works great.

Comment: @jonrsharp The bad behaviour is some other exception like a ValueError, or a AttributeError, etc.

Comment: But shouldn't they be covered in separate test cases?

Comment: i'd say you should have a function that returns one consistent thing if all is well, and one consistent thing if something bad happened. don't have different good cases that are equivalent in the sense that they're good cause different things you have to test for separately.

Comment: i'm thinking of a function called something like all_well that returns True or False. then your test would check that it returns True when it should and False when it should, for different conditions. (different tests for different cases.)